# Graph API- get the channel name in calendar events

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am utilizing the Graph API calendar resource to retrieve events (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events). In the event that a channel is chosen in the attendee section (refer to the screenshot), my objective is to obtain the specifics of that particular channel.
It appears that Microsoft Teams stores the Channel name in a location, as evidenced by the display of the selected channel name when editing a meeting that was created. However, I have not discovered any information related to the channel in the Graph API endpoint.
Is there a method for me to access this information?
[image]

Comment: Could you please let us know which Graph API query you are using?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT, I am using this query https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events

Comment: We checked and these doesn't seem to be any way to get channel information. To achieve your requirements, we recommend you give your feedback in [Teams Feedback Portal](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472).

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I have updated my question with a screenshot, in case I was not clear the last time. Please recheck and let me know if there is any way to get this.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the channel details of a calendar event by following below steps:

1. Make a call to graph "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendar/events" and search for the event you created by name.
2. Then get the **joinURL** property and extract the **channel id**
   [image]
3. Next, call graph again to list all channels and filter it with the channel id and then get the respective channel's display name.

Comment: thanks @prasad-MSFT for providing this workaround.